# vino on Ubuntu 18.04, how to change default port 5900

Tags: 18.04, vino

I'm use Xorg option and normally SSH into this machine and forward X. I wanted to change 5900 port as part of security layer.

I've tried old method of using dconf-editor to change default port with effect.

I suppose there is a command line was via gsetting or gconftool but I cannot find it and the Archwiki refers to a vin38 which I also cannot find.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I installed _vino_ in Lubuntu 18.04 and tried to set-up password etc using _dconf-editor_ (`vino-preferences` does nothing), but I cannot log-in to that computer's desktop remotely. Did you use _dconf-editor_ to set it up?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your previous answer you deleted, sorry for the -1. If the actual problem is that _vino_ did not work at all, I mean at any port, probably the problem is that _vino_ needs a _base64_ encoded password, but _dconf-editor_ cannot set this password to _vino_. I think I found the solution to the problem, if the actual problem is not connecting at all, can post answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working for us:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino alternative-port 5901
```

Execute as the user for which you enabled vino in Gnome settings.